# Why won't my Skyrim load from the main menu?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360, technical-issues

I am having problems with not even getting to play the game. I got the game for Christmas and I played it for a while and then stopped. The next time I tried it, I press play and choose my storage device, then two seconds later it freezes completely. But if I play as a guest without saving I can start a new game. My sister is in a different place in the game and the same thing happens to her. My dad hasn't even started and it happens with him if you press load. We all play on different storage devices and I have cleared the cache multiple times. I deleted all older saves and it still does the same thing.

I was really enjoying the game, so what do I do? I play on Xbox 360 with a disk and DLC  with Hearthfire, Dragonborn and Dawnguard

Comment: What storage devices are you all using? Also, are all your system updates up-to-date?

Comment: are you changing storage devices while the game is off?, if not you may have corrupted your saved data. are you choosing the storage device when the game begins?

Comment: I am using a usb but its got 18 gb my sister used a built in flashdrive 4 gb my dad uses another external flashdrive. How do you update a disk.  Yes i am choosing it on the loading screen but we all use different storages and the exact same thing happens.

Comment: Wow, I wish my family played Skyrim as yours jajaja, they rather play The Sims :(

Answer (score 2):

Since effectively the same thing is happening across storage devices and saves, it is unlikely that this is a corrupted save or bad hard disk problem, and much more likely the game disk is scratched.  If you were using a PC I would recommend backing up your saves, then reinstalling the game via digital download.  As you are on Xbox, there may be digital download options available, otherwise you may need to get another copy of the game.